# LINQ intersect?

Tags: linq

I have two tables in form of these clases

```
public class Movie
{
    private int MovieID;
    private string Title;
}
public class transactions
{
    private int TransactionID;
    private int MovieID;

}
```

so first table contains ALL movies 2nd contains movies which are RENTED

How do I select ALL movies that are left in the store , ie not rented and are available. Tried soething like:

```
var moviesavailable =
  (from m in db.Movies 
  select m.MovieID ).Intersect
  (from trans in db.Transactions 
  select trans.MovieID)
```

but not working...

Comment: Normally you would use `Except` but as your objects are of different type you can't use it in this case. An intersection is the oposite of what you want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First way to do it is go over all movies and for each look if there is no transaction with the same MovieID:

```
db.Movies.Where(m => !db.Transactions.Any(t => t.MovieID == m.MovieID))
```

Second way is to make left join. We join all rows from Movies and their equivalent rows from Transactions. If there is no row in Transactions for a row in Movies, then for this row the transaction is null (DefaultIfEmpty):

```
from m in db.Movies
join t in db.Transactions on m.MovieID equals t.MovieID into g
from t in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
where t == null
select m.MovieID
```

Comment: Wow this is awesome!!! thnx

if only I could understand it it would be great but its important its working :)

I had much uglier solution

Comment: Oh, it's very important to understand it. I added some words. Tell me if you need more.